# How to retrieve a calculated column value using sp.web SPFX

Tags: spfx

I am creating an SPFX (ReactJS/TypeScript) webpart and using:

```
let docs = sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Case Documents").items.select("ID","Title","CaseID").orderBy("Modified", true).get();
```

to attempt to retrieve column values from a SharePoint DOC library. 
CaseID is a lookup column looking at an SP list. There are values in the lookup column populated from that other list.

I can get Id and Title values from the library but not CaseID (lookup column).
I get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable [400]  ::> 
{"odata.error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":
{"lang":"en-US","value":"The query to field 'CaseID' is not valid. 
The $select query string must specify the target fields and the $expand query string must contains CaseID."}}}
    at new HttpRequestError (parsers.js:130)
    at Function.<anonymous> (parsers.js:145)
    at step (tslib.es6.js:99)
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:80)
    at fulfilled (tslib.es6.js:70)
HttpRequestError @ parsers.js:130
(anonymous) @ parsers.js:145
step @ tslib.es6.js:99
(anonymous) @ tslib.es6.js:80
fulfilled @ tslib.es6.js:70
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get lookup values for your lookup column value by:

```
let docs = sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Case Documents").items.select("ID","Title","CaseID/Title", "CaseID/ID").expand("CaseID").orderBy("Modified", true).get();
```

Comment: sorry, my bad, updated the answer, please check now. forgot to include `expand()` for lookup column

Comment: Hi - yes it is: Field=CaseID
It's a lookup field

Comment: Hi - it's now giving another error:

Minified: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {odata.type, odata.id, Title, ID}).

Comment: Is it possibly to do with what columns are in the source list?

Comment: can you paste a snap shot of your source list columns/structure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208978/discussion-between-tom-and-muhammad-murad-haider).

Comment: Muhammed solved it by adding this to my render:
Where the lookup column CaseID was being referenced (real name Title), it required a string to be passed not the object, so: <td style={{ width: '100px' }}>{item.CaseID.Title}</td>